# trouble rendering view in deno/oak

Tags: deno, oak

I'm using deno, oak, and view_engine.
Here is my file structure:

```
server.ts
routes
  user.ts
view
  index.ejs
  /user
    index.ejs
```

On my server.js this code works as expected:

```
router
  .get("/", (context: any) => {
    context.render("view/index.ejs");
  });
```

But, in my routes/user.ts, the following code does NOT work:

```
router
  .get("user/", (ctx: any) => {
    ctx.render("../view/user/index.ejs")
  });
```

Inside render, I tried:

```
${Deno.cwd}"/../view/student/index.ejs"
"/../view/user/index.ejs"
```

and out of desperation:

```
"/view/user/index.ejs"
```

I'm sure there's a super easy, most obvious thing I'm missing here.

Comment: what's showing the error log?

Answer (score 0):

Here is workaround,

```
import { Application, send, Router } from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";
import { viewEngine, engineFactory, adapterFactory, ViewConfig } from 'https://deno.land/x/view_engine/mod.ts';

const ejsEngine = engineFactory.getEjsEngine();
const oakAdapter = adapterFactory.getOakAdapter();

const app = new Application();

app.use(viewEngine(oakAdapter, ejsEngine, {
    viewRoot: "./view",
    viewExt: ".ejs",
}));

const router = new Router();

app.use(router.routes());
app.use(router.allowedMethods());

router
    .get('/', async (ctx, next) => {
        ctx.render("index", { data: { name: "Nikhil" } });
    });

await app.listen({ port: 8000 });
```

Inside the view folder i have `index.ejs`

Run files as,

> deno run --allow-net --allow-read server.ts
>
> index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>EJS HOLA</h1>
    Hobbies of <%=data.name%>

</body>

</html>
```

For more resource to add, you can look at [view_engine](https://deno.land/x/view_engine)

Comment: was still giving me [ERROR]: Property 'render' does not exist on type 'RouterContext<Record<string | number, string | undefined>, Record<string, any>>'.  but, after pegging oak to v6.0.0, everything worked.

Comment: may be you are misleading argumensts at some point, can you share your code snippet